# what the logical/physical pair means?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, comparatives

In English, we often use logical/physical pair to describe something, like in powerdesigner,

there are two type of data models:

> logical data model and physical data model

what's this words means?

Comment: I mean, In genearal, not just in computer world.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on context, since it's often jargon rather than straight English.

When that pair is used in the computer industry, "logical" generally refers to the behavior as seen by the user, and "physical" refers to what's happening at the hardware level to provide that behavior. For example, a RAID disk-storage unit appear to be one logical disk drive to the operating system, while its physical implementation is actually a group of disk drives with the data spread among them.

Comment: is there any general meaning? not just in computer world

Comment: Just the dictionary meanings. Logical meaning related to logic, occasionally used to mean "conceptual" or "reasonable". Physical meaning related to objects or bodies (cognate of physics and physique respectively).